# What is the highest sampling frequency the iWatch can use to measure heart rate?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I'm building an app which requires frequent readings from the heart rate sensor on the watch. I know that throughout the day the watch will sample heart rate at ~10 minutes intervals and during an exercise session it can be as frequent as ~5 seconds using `HKWorkoutActivityTypeRunning` with `HKWorkoutSessionLocationTypeIndoor`.

Is this the highest frequency at which the watch can measure heart rate with?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apple Watch records heart rates most frequently when the user is recording a workout.